# I have used Jersey bean validation,i have passed a message which according to some articles should show the message if the validation fails

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, bean-validation

I have used Jersey bean validation,in the @Size or any other annotation's () ,i have passed a message which according to some articles should show the message if the validation fails i am unable to see the message and only generic message appears
here is the pom file

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!---->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

this is my POJO class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Access {
    
    @Min(value = 1, message ="AccessId should not be less than 1")
    @Max(value = 100, message ="AccessId should not be greater than 100")
    private int accessId;
    
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50, message="Acccesses has to be more than 3 characters and less than 50 characters")
    @NotNull(message = "Accesses can not be null")
    private String accesses;
//getters & setters
```

and the attached is the response i'm getting in postman on hitting the api,
[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL5BF.png)

the resource class's post method is annotated with @valid

```
@POST
    @Path("create")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Access createAccess(@Valid Access a1)
{
//code for fetching data 
}
```

My web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.accessmgt3.AccessManagement3</param-value>
        </init-param>    
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: ,please clearly explain what you are doing before you actually explain and give code, as there could be multiple solutions to a problem.

Comment: sure, so i have added @NotNull,@Size ,etc,jersey bean validations annotations which have a message specified in them suppose the object(in this case Access a1) fails to follow those constraints, my issue is that i'm getting the 400 bad request as expected but i am not getting the exact message that i have specified. i have attached web.xml file. i dont have a class that extends to resouceconfig.